# Создать рамку состоящую из изображений

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

Мне необходимо динамически генерировать рамку вокруг существующего `ImageView` (размеры бывают разные) из 4 разных частей: лево, право, верх, низ.

Какие есть варианты решения данной задачи, кто-нибудь сталкивался?

p.s. возможно можно создать прямоугольник, через `bitmap` и в него уже добавлять изображения, пока ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

1. Рисовать на `Bitmap` через `Canvas` прямоугольник в центре и рамки.
2. Сделать вокруг 4 `ImageView` и менять на них изображение.